# whenever I try to configure room, converse.js disconnects. Why?

Tags: ejabberd, converse.js

I installed `converse.js` in my server and got it connected to `ejabberd` using ejabberd's `BOSH`. Ejabberd is also installed in my server. Now when i create a room, the room is created, I can invite users. But when I go to the configuration page, `converse.js` hangs and disconnects and does not allow me to configure the room at all. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to enable some configuration in ejabberd?

Comment: Take a look at what your client sends, and what replies the server. Maybe the server returns some meaningful error stanza to the client.

Comment: I will try that. Let me see if converse also creates log files or not. Thanks.

Comment: If you have only a user, and the traffic is not encrypted, you can sniff the traffic in realtime with something like: sudo tcpflow -i lo -Cg port 5222